# Sending email without ending in junk/spam of end users - PHP

Tags: php, email, joomla, spam

I have a Joomla site where I use this module [Simple Email Form](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/simple-email-form) and I have the problem that when responding to a user it often ends in junk/spam folders. I've looked at the code and this module is using JFactory::getMailer(); and it is only using the `addRecipient()`, `setSender()`, `setSubject()`, `setBody()` and I have set the `isHTML()` to true in the JFactory object.

I have tested my mail with this site: http://www.isnotspam.com/
and got this result: [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/sS8DPzw0)

I'm don't really understand how email work and what parts are important, but I think this is probably the problem:

```
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=example@example.com
Selector=
domain=
DomainKeys DNS Record=
```

Could someone tell me how to send a email the right way and I want to be able to promise to my client that their mails won't end in theirs clients spam/junk folders.

If it is easier to move away from JFactory to something else I am willing to do this also :)

Comment: Your server ip might have been blacklisted, or your email body or subject contains 'spam'-susspicios text. It will also depend on receiving email server. I have seen lots of situations, when say Gmail will treat email as spam while Yahoo doesn't, the same goes with your own email servers. Search google for "rbl check"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a shared server than probably the score for that server is bad. If you are using your own server probably it's neutral but sometimes will go to spam because the server does not have a good reputation and depends how each email provider see that email.

Best solution I see it's to integrate a mailing service. In this way they promise that emails will not go to spam.
I don't know how many emails you are sending / month.
There are some that offer free email / month. Depends on volume. 
For example:

1. [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) - 12.000 free emails / month and they have [official
   PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) . Tested no problem with spam.
2. [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com/) - 10.000 free
   emails / month. Did not test this one but it's from rackspace
3. [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) - no free emails, part of mailchimp. Tested and work ok, but no more free emails. Tested no problem with spam.
4. [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) - 62.000 free emails / month for first year if you use free tier. Tested no problem with spam.